# Tracing ancestors in what is now Romania?

Tags: romania

I travelled to Romania in 2014 in hopes of finding some church birth, marriage, death etc records and came away with none because we arrived late Friday and left late Sunday. Although I did take back with me lovely memories of Szatmar.

I am looking for information on the Andras Murin family. Andras married Maria Kraska.  I was told they were both born in Szatmar Megye,  Sarkoz Ujlak.  They had many children one being my grandmother Elizabeth.

How can this information help me in finding out more information about my family.   The Boc, Joseph name is whom my grandmother Elizabeth Murin married.

Comment: Do you have any dates you can share with us?

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Without more details, especially dates (even approximate) of the events you mention, probably all I can suggest is to review how others are researching their Romanian ancestors here: http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/romania

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you haven't begun attempting your search. There is no magic key to getting your answers. It takes research and learning about what Romanian records there are.

There are many different avenues for Romanian genealogical research. I recommend starting off by searching Google for "Genealogy Romania" and you'll be swamped by all the different suggestions you'll get.

Enjoy the adventure. Initial discoveries are exciting.

And next time before you visit your mother country again, do you homework first. Know as many names, places, events and dates as possible so that you'll be able to recognize relevant information. Learn in advances about the archives, libraries and cemeteries you want information from as well as the rules for visiting each. Plan where you will go and when. If you can, hire a guide who knows the area and the language.